# table sort function not working outside of fiddle

Tags: jquery, sorting, tablesorter

The fiddle below works perfectly but when I try to re-create this in a blank test document, nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/1djad595/2/

This is updated code that I cant get to replicate the success of the fiddle above. .

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css" />

</head>


<body>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#myTable").tablesorter(); 
    } 
); 

    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.27.8/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js">
</script> 
<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter"> 
<thead> 
<tr> 
    <th>Last Name</th> 
    <th>First Name</th> 
    <th>Email</th> 
    <th>Due</th> 
    <th>Web Site</th> 
</tr> 
</thead> 
<tbody> 
<tr> 
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>John</td> 
    <td>jsmith@gmail.com</td> 
    <td>$50.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.jsmith.com</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td>Bach</td> 
    <td>Frank</td> 
    <td>fbach@yahoo.com</td> 
    <td>$50.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.frank.com</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td>Doe</td> 
    <td>Jason</td> 
    <td>jdoe@hotmail.com</td> 
    <td>$100.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.jdoe.com</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td>Conway</td> 
    <td>Tim</td> 
    <td>tconway@earthlink.net</td> 
    <td>$50.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.timconway.com</td> 
</tr> 
</tbody> 
</table> 


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you forgot to include libraries (jQuery + tablesorter) [updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1djad595/2/)

Comment: Thank you much i knew it would be something silly I overlooked. How does one get the arrows indicating it is sortable?

Comment: Just add their stylesheet Hope this link helps
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11763352/jquery-tablesorter-the-sorting-arrows-dont-show

Comment: Ill look further into that. The css style that I had added was copied from the green. Maybe I missed something. Speaking of missing something, the fiddler works great. I even re-created it myself and it works. However in my test example on my comp, I cant make it work. Have I done something silly again? Ive updated the code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to include the script libraries in the code in the correct order first the jQuery libarary and then the tablesorter

If you copy the following code it must work for you:

```js
$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#myTable").tablesorter(); 
    } 
);
```

```css
table.tablesorter {
 font-size: 12px;
 background-color: #4D4D4D;
 width: 100%;
 border: 1px solid #000;
}
table.tablesorter th {
 text-align: left;
 padding: 5px;
 background-color: #6E6E6E;
 color: #fff;
}
table.tablesorter td {
 color: #FFF;
 padding: 5px;
}
table.tablesorter .even {
 background-color: #3D3D3D;
}
table.tablesorter .odd {
 background-color: #6E6E6E;
}
table.tablesorter .header {
 background-image: url(bg.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 border-left: 1px solid #FFF;
 border-right: 1px solid #000;
 border-top: 1px solid #FFF;
 padding-left: 30px;
 padding-top: 8px;
 height: auto;
}
table.tablesorter .headerSortUp {
 background-image: url(asc.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
table.tablesorter .headerSortDown {
 background-image: url(desc.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.27.8/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>

<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter"> 
<thead> 
<tr> 
    <th>Last Name</th> 
    <th>First Name</th> 
    <th>Email</th> 
    <th>Due</th> 
    <th>Web Site</th> 
</tr> 
</thead> 
<tbody> 
<tr> 
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>John</td> 
    <td>jsmith@gmail.com</td> 
    <td>$50.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.jsmith.com</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td>Bach</td> 
    <td>Frank</td> 
    <td>fbach@yahoo.com</td> 
    <td>$50.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.frank.com</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td>Doe</td> 
    <td>Jason</td> 
    <td>jdoe@hotmail.com</td> 
    <td>$100.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.jdoe.com</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td>Conway</td> 
    <td>Tim</td> 
    <td>tconway@earthlink.net</td> 
    <td>$50.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.timconway.com</td> 
</tr> 
</tbody> 
</table>
```

Comment: @brett I think you need only to include the jquey and the tablesorter library in the correct order good luck :)

Comment: This did it for me. I did not know that the order mattered provided everything ran. Thank you for this answer!